# Passing an IList<> as parameter via curl

Tags: .net, wcf, curl, azure

I've created an Azure WCF Service and i want to serve RESTful requests. One of them requires an IList list as a parameter, but i can't make it wirk and i don't know if i use curl wrong or defined the service wrong. I give you the code:

The interface class:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "generate", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    HttpResponseMessage Generate(IList<string> valami);
```

The service.svc.cs:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Generate(IList<string> valami)
    {

        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
        <listeners>
            <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
              name="AzureDiagnostics">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

and that's how i use curl:

```
curl.exe -i -X POST http://127.0.0.1:81/PowerpointService.svc/generate -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @ilistcontent.json
```

where the ilistcontent.json is: ["egy","ketto","harom","negy"]

thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (just from examples I saw on the web) that the JSON should be `{"valami": ["egy", "ketto", "harom", "negy"]}`.